# web queries in MS EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automate several web queries in MS EXCEL VBA for an app I'm building at work basically as a MACRO to assemble information from our corprate web sites. I assume they use server side scripting because the documents are all presented under a single URL with no parameters. As a result the EXCEL web query method is impossible. I am able to programatically open the required sites, but there are layers upon layers of navigation required to reach the desired output. On the opening page, however, there is an .onclick function that holds a parameter string used to call specified documents. The code and web information are sensitive so I cannot post any real code, but the .onclick looks a lot like this in the source:

```
IEdoc.TD.item(i).onclick="fnFtch('MBSOVY07OZ-LIMO/TVDBLDAT#WNISAZÿNÿALLÿTÿIÿÿ ÿ24ÿ ÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ ÿÿ ÿMÿÿNÿNO');"
```

If I assign it a variable like this:

```
strgvar = IEdoc.TD.item(i).onclick or set objvar = IEdoc.TD.item(i).onclick
```

The result is more like:

```
function(){'fnFtch('MBSOVY07OZ-LIMO/TVDBLDAT#WNISAZÿNÿALLÿTÿIÿÿ ÿ24ÿ ÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ ÿÿ ÿMÿÿNÿNO');'}
```

I want to change the part of the string following the "#" to the parameters I would eventually end up with following several pages of programatic navigation.
Went I replace the unwanted portion with the string I want, .click ceases to do anything.
It's obvious to me that I'm mixing "string" and "object" properties because if I do this:

```
Set objvar = IEdic.TD.item(i).onclick
strgvar = objvar
IEdoc.TD.item(i).onclick = strgvar
```

The .click fails to work.

If I leave everything "object" type like this:

```
Set objvar = IEdoc.TD.item(i).onclick
IEdoc.TD.item(i).onclick = objvar
```

The .click still works
None of this codes returns a "Type mismatch" error, it just renders the .click inert

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using navigate and Document.documentElement.innerHTML to read the text on the page? I used FireBug to trace one website and had to go to two pages for every page that you saw (first page was the "request", the second page actually gave you the content). Very cumbersome, but I got it to work with Navigate.

Answer (score 0):

`FireEvent` is used to trigger the event attached to any element. Try below code.

```
Set objvar = IEdic.TD.item(i)
objvar.FireEvent("onclick")
```